# API data not showing on html page | AfterViewInit | Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

I am to Angular 14 and I'm practicing with custom services. The following service is returning data, I checked it with my console box  i attach image, but data are not showing on page.

My HTML

```
<table id="leadTable" class="table display">
        <thead class="table-heading">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let leading of leadings">
            <td class="priceLabel">{{ leading.amount }}</td>
            <td class="otherLabel">{{ leading.status }}</td>
            <td class="otherLabel">{{ leading.date }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

My ts file:

```
import { TablesService } from './tables.service';
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Table} from './table.model'
declare const $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tables',
  templateUrl: './tables.component.html',
})
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit  {

  // public leadings: Table[];
  leadings: Table[];
  constructor(private TablesService: TablesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLeadings()
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $('#leadTable').DataTable();
  }

  ngClick() {
    this.getLeadings()
  }

  private getLeadings() {
      this.TablesService.getLeadings().subscribe(leadings => this.leadings = leadings);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could we see the `TablesService` code? Also, are you using Angular Datatables?

Comment: @mondieki my normal data not listing  :::::::

  private baseURL = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getLeadings(): Observable<Table[]> {
    return this.http.get<Table[]>(this.baseURL + '/leadings');
  }